# NullPointerException using a "Receive Task"

Tags: jbpm, kie-workbench

I created a simple business process containing a "Receive Task" and a "Script Task". However, after running the instance just for once I keep getting the below error and I can't proceed.

**INFO:**
Could not open requested business process due to processing errors. 
Empty process was loaded instead.
Click on the Details tab below to view error details.

**DETAILS:**
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oorg.jbpm.designer.bpmn2.impl.Bpmn2JsonMarshaller.marshallTask(Bpmn2JsonMarshaller.java:1825)
    at (etc..I can give the rest of the information if needed later)

How can I start resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the parser is expecting some data to be there, but it's not, causing a NPE.  Could you specify which version of jBPM you are using?  The file in question can be found here, but to match the line you would have to select the right tag:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-designer/blob/master/jbpm-designer-backend/src/main/java/org/jbpm/designer/bpmn2/impl/Bpmn2JsonMarshaller.java